# hitting times and stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

stopping times are always hitting times, but not the other way around. As an example of this, Last exit times are not stopping times as they depend on future information.

the last exit time of $A$: some subset of the state space $S$:
$$
\tau = \max \{n \ge 0 | X_n \in A \}
$$
How do we think about this as a hitting time? Is it simply the first hit time of $S - A$, this doesn't seem right though since the process could still return to $A$ after leaving it.

Comment: "stopping times are always hitting times" No. Hitting times are always stopping times but lots of stopping times are not hitting times. "Last exit times are not stopping times" True, nobody says they are, and they are not hitting times either.

Comment: @Did is there a difference between last exit times and exit times? The first line of the WP page on hitting times mentions that exit times are examples of hitting times?

Comment: "Exit time" usually refers to the *first* exit time, that is, $\inf\{n\mid X_n\notin A\}$. A whole different story from the *last* exit time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misspoke somewhat in your first statement: first hitting times are stopping times, but there are many other kinds of stopping times. What you've written is a last exit time, which is *not* a stopping time, because as you've said we cannot know whether $\tau \leq t$ by observing the process up to time $t$. This creates some difficulties in transition path theory (where we are interested in the time when we exit $A$ and will hit $B$ before returning to $A$ again).

Comment: I actually wrote that it is a last exit time? My problem is in trying to relate this definition of a last exit time back to that of a 'hitting time'. Usually when I learned about hitting times we deal with first hitting time, so I was asking if we can relate last exit to first hitting by thinking about last exit as a first hit of the complement

Comment: oh, i see what you meant about my first statement, edited now.